# Select the last number via regex when identifying (string + number)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following words:

> Say.2 Sing"3 Final5 Note:10 Music99 Sing1

I need you to look like this with the `(string + number)`:

[image]

I've tried it this way:

```
[^\s\d]\d+
```

But always comes a string before and not the number:

[image]

I'm replacing these numbers at the end with `\n` via code in C#. I just need a valid regex.

```
private void method()
{
    string text = "Say.2 Sing"3 Final5 Note:10 Music99 Sing1";
    string ntext = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\s\d]\d+", "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(ntext);
}
```

But in output it is like this:

```
Say
Sing
Fina
Note
Musi
Sin
```

I need you to look like this:

```
Say.    
Sing"    
Final    
Note:    
Music
Sing
```

Comment: why not just `\d+`?

Comment: it's because I have a text and in that text there are some words with the pattern (string + number) and I need to remove the number at the end

Comment: but `\d+` will perfectly match all your yellow markings. Have you tried it?

Comment: I need to have a string before the number and so select that number

Comment: Then use the positive lookbehind contruct: `(?<=[^\s\d])\d+`. This matches a sequence of digits when preceded by anything except whitespace or digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "Say.2 Sing\"3 Final5 Note:10 Music99 Sing1";
        var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<![\s0-9])[0-9]+\s*", "\n");
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##TY4xT8MwEIXn@FdcPSW0jVoQQxpQKyHYykAqMTQMrjlVlowd@ZwqFepvD2fowHKnu6f3vadprn3AcezJuCM0Z4r4VYv/V7nDIZZveOytCs9DF5DIeEe1ANH1B2s0aKuIYIcUxbfIrk@KKvI6efMJW2VcXoiM1eykAkRGwiPIRp3LW2g4rJV38GKcsvfw6iOulgvYcgtdVb/yUtZXK8f3Npm5EQ7cq7NKY56IM9jIfP0w2be0mFcfxT7NaUs3cgaydbJIjCeu7i2W78FEzP9oSbiIyzj@AA)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s0-9]                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a capturing group capturing what you want to keep, and match what you want to remove.

In the replacement use group 1 and a newline.

```
([^\d\s]+)\d+\s*
```

- `([^\d\s]+)` capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than a digit or a whiteapace char
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits (Or use `[0-9]` to match digits 0-9)
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%5cd%5cs%5d%2b%29%5cd%2b%5cs*&i=Say.2+Sing%223+Final5+Note%3a10+Music99+Sing1&r=%241%5cn) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Jzos5v)

```
string text = "Say.2 Sing\"3 Final5 Note:10 Music99 Sing1";
string ntext = Regex.Replace(text, @"([^\d\s]+)\d+\s*", "$1\n");
Console.WriteLine(ntext);
```

Output

```
Say.
Sing"
Final
Note:
Music
Sing
```

[image]